# HTML5 Validacion no permitir navegadores web antiguos

Tags: php, html5, formularios, validación

les hago una consulta arme una web y valide con html5 los formularios, required type number,email etc. ahora con navegadores viejos que no soportan html5 saltarian la validacion. conocen alguna manera de no permitir navegadores que no soporten validaciones html5?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que se me ocurre es que realices una consulta con tu pagina index.php y coloques este codigo que consigui en PHP para que valides la version del navegador que esta leyendo tu pagina. si este corresponde a la lista de los soportados por la version y modelos entonces le permites el acceso, de lo contrario le indicas que deberian actualizarse.

**Este es el link donde saque el codigo:**

https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/PHP/2499-Detectar-el-sistema-operativo-navegador-y-version-del-cliente.html

```
<?php
/**
 * Función para detectar el sistema operativo, navegador y versión del mismo
 */
$info=detect();

echo "Sistema operativo: ".$info["os"];
echo "Navegador: ".$info["browser"];
echo "Versión: ".$info["version"];
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

/**
 * Funcion que devuelve un array con los valores:
 *  os => sistema operativo
 *  browser => navegador
 *  version => version del navegador
 */
function detect()
{
    $browser=array("IE","OPERA","MOZILLA","NETSCAPE","FIREFOX","SAFARI","CHROME");
    $os=array("WIN","MAC","LINUX");

    # definimos unos valores por defecto para el navegador y el sistema operativo
    $info['browser'] = "OTHER";
    $info['os'] = "OTHER";

    # buscamos el navegador con su sistema operativo
    foreach($browser as $parent)
    {
        $s = strpos(strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']), $parent);
        $f = $s + strlen($parent);
        $version = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $f, 15);
        $version = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.]/','',$version);
        if ($s)
        {
            $info['browser'] = $parent;
            $info['version'] = $version;
        }
    }

    # obtenemos el sistema operativo
    foreach($os as $val)
    {
        if (strpos(strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),$val)!==false)
            $info['os'] = $val;
    }

    # devolvemos el array de valores
    return $info;
}
?>
```

LA salida en pantalla es la siguiente:

En CHROME

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN FIREFOX

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN EDGE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]